# Revoke MS Office 2013 license

Tags: microsoft-office, license

A laptop I don't have anymore has a copy of MS Office 2013 Professional installed on it. I don't want the person who now has it to have a free license since I paid for it.

Is there a way to revoke the license so it will not work anymore?

**Edit**

This is a Microsoft Office Professional 2013 Home Use license purchased through https://www.microsofthup.com

Comment: What license *type* is this? Office 365? Retail? Bought with the laptop originally?

Comment: @Twisty see edit

Comment: Reading the [WHOIS on microsofthup.com](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results-v2.jsp?domain=microsofthup.com) is scarey.  The site claims to be run by digital river for Microsoft in the footer, but examining the domain registration info the site doesn't see too legit IMO anyway.  good luck.

Comment: @Tyson The site is legit.  It's referenced on [this Microsoft.com webpage](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/home-use-program.aspx) as the correct site from which to by HUP licenses.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** Since you no longer have physical access to the laptop and you're not using an Office 365 license, there's no way to disable the license.

What you have is a [Home Use](http://www.microsofthup.com/hupus/faq.aspx?culture=en-US) license:

> The Home Use Program is a Software Assurance benefit available to Microsoft volume licensing customers with active Software Assurance coverage on their Office applications.  Employees who use the covered licenses at work are eligible to purchase these Office applications for use on a home PC during the term of their employment.  This temporary license expires with the employers Software Assurance coverage, or upon termination of employment with the covered customer.

This license type does not report back to a Web-based console like Office 365 licenses, so there's no way to remotely deactivate it.